# Snapping in PyQGIS3.0

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, snapping

The following expression enables snapping for PyQGIS 2.0 :

```
QgsProject.instance().setSnapSettingsForLayer(layer.id(), True, 2, 1, 10, True)
```

What is the equivalent expression in PyQGIS 3.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PyQGIS 3, according to the [PyQGIS documentation of the QgsProject class](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Project/QgsProject.html), the snapping settings are contained in a `QgsSnappingConfig` object passed to the `QgsProject` instance.

So in PyQGIS 3, the expression becomes something like this:

```
my_snap_config = QgsSnappingConfig()
my_snap_config.setEnabled(True)
my_snap_config.setType(QgsSnappingConfig.VertexAndSegment)
my_snap_config.setUnits(QgsTolerance.Pixels)
my_snap_config.setTolerance(10)
my_snap_config.setIntersectionSnapping(True)

QgsProject.instance().setSnappingConfig(my_snap_config)
```

using the `setMode` method of `QgsSnappingConfig` it is possible to define the snapping for all the layers, for the active layer or to create a per-layer configuration.

Comment: Many thanks Marioba. It works perfectly. For snapping with all layers, we can add : my_snap_config.setMode(QgsSnappingConfig.AllLayers)